# awk print substr() by character index, ignoring the space at the end of substr

Tags: string, bash, awk

I have a data like this

```
12345678901234567890123456789012345678 // this line just character index //
a0001 some text           other_data_1
a0002 some_text_connected other_data_2
a0003                     other_data_3
```

In substr($0, 7, 20) of each line, there are some text. I could print the note text by

```
awk '{print substr($0,7,20)}' testfile
```

and get:

```
some text          
some_text_connected
(20 spaces here)
```

1. How could **delete the space at the end of each substr**($0, 7,20) and print the text?
2. If a substr($0, 7,20) is empty, print N/A instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the next string function from `sub` in this list : [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-40) . Good luck.

Comment: there would not be any `(20 spaces here)` - there will be just an empty line without spaces

Comment: Look here https://ibb.co/kQQ9Ym

Comment: There may be spaces in character  index from 7 to 26, $2 may only recognize part of the text within that range, like the second line of the sample data.@EdMorton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `sub` to strip all trailing space:

```
awk '{s = substr($0,7,20); sub(/[[:blank:]]+$/, "", s); print (s == "" ? "NA" : s)}' file
```

`print (s == "" ? "NA" : s)` will print `NA` if string `s` is empty otherwise `s` is printed.

Comment: Would you mind to explain in details how `/[[:blank:]]+$/` represent the trailing spaces of the substr? Thanks. @anubhava

Comment: In the `sub` function, regex `[[:blank:]]+$` checks for trailing white-spaces after `substr` function and removes it. Expression `print (s == "" ? "NA" : s)` prints `NA` if string `s` is empty otherwise string `s` is printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :
With awk

```
awk 'NF==1{$2="NA"}{$1="";sub(" ","")}1' testfile
```

or with sed

```
sed -E 's/([^ ]* )(..*)/\2/;t;s/.*/NA/' testfile
```